# Can we manage the silent print always by PHP or Jquery

Tags: printing

print.print_always_silent use to print the page without print dialog box. My question is, can we do this my PHP / JQUERY code?. Please Help me how know well abt this.

Answer (score 0):

I hope not. That would mean any website could print any document from my printer when they want. Would be a huge security hole imho

Comment: Hey this is Web application and going to used by my client.

Comment: But if you can make it work for that one clients, you can make it work for random visitors.
Also, might be a userinterface problem, people are used to getting the confirm screen. Not showing one might cause accidental prints

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not possible through the browser with PHP, which runs on the server. It's also not possible with javascript: browser security ensures that. Imagine what might happen if any web site could print whenever it wanted to.

There are (or were) ActiveX controls available for IE that enabled this. It might be possible with a browser extension for Chrome or Firefox if you want to explore that.

One other possibility is setting up a printer on Google Cloud Print and having your PHP server print directly to that, bypassing the browser altogether. Handling the authentication behind such a scheme could be tricky, but the API is documented on Google's site.